# Split based on dynamic variable and keep separator in array

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split an array based on a dynamic separator that will change, and keep the separator in the resulting array.

Consider the following example where I need to:

- Split `const match = 'somethingcatsomethingcatsomethingcat'`
- using the separator `const separator = 'cat'`
- and get the following array as a result: `["something", "cat", "something", "cat", "something", "cat"]`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
const separator = 'cat'
const match = 'somethingcatsomethingcatsomethingcat'

const standardSplit = match.split(separator)
console.log(standardSplit)
// >> Array ["something", "something", "something", ""]

const withPureRegex = match.split(/(cat)/)
console.log(withPureRegex)
// >> Array ["something", "cat", "something", "cat", "something", "cat", ""]
// This is what I need, without the last element of an empty string.
// But I need to pass in the separator dynamically.

const regex = new RegExp(`/(${separator})/`, 'gi')
const withStringLiteral = match.split(regex)
console.log(withStringLiteral)
// >> Array ["somethingcatsomethingcatsomethingcat"]
```

I'm no good with regex. I've read some [articles](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping#summary) about escaping in regex, but it seems it's not necessary within `RegExp`? I tried many variations of the `RegExp` with no luck.

There are a good number of questions regarding this, but only few I've found that attempt to do it with a dynamic separator. The few questions I found had answers using string literals and `RegExp` like I have above.

If I needed to do this only once, I would use a non-regex approach, like using the first `split` method above and then manually looping through to insert the separator as needed. But in this case I'm running this match/replace many times and can't add more overhead if it could be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the last empty item using `.filter(Boolean)`.

**Demo:**

```js
const match = 'somethingcatsomethingcatsomethingcat';
const separator = 'cat';

const reg = new RegExp(`(${separator})`, 'g');
const resArr = match.split(reg).filter(Boolean);

console.log(resArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split on matches of the regular expression

```
(?<!^| ) *(?=cat)|(?<=cat) *(?! |$)
```

The expression reads, "match zero or more spaces provided they are not proceeded by a space or at the beginning of the string, and are followed by `"cat"` *or* (`|`) match zero or more spaces provided they are preceded by `"cat"` and are not followed by a space or are at the end of the string.

`(?=cat)` is a *positive lookahead*; `(?<=cat)` is a *positive lookbehind*.  `(?<!^| )` is a *negative lookbehind*; `(?! |$)` is a *negative lookahead*.

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81P8CT/1)

The link demonstrates that the two strings

```
"catsomethingcatsomethingcat"
"cat somethingcatsomething cat"
```

are both split to form the array

```
["cat", "something", "cat", "something", "cat"]
```

---

Notice that the spaces in the second string are removed, rather than be being left with, say, `" something"`.

Observe that some of the matches on which the string is split may be zero-width, such as when splitting the string `"catsomething"` into `"cat"` and `"something"`.

The goofy `(?<! |^)` is to split, for example, `"  catsomething"` into `" cat"` and `"something"`. Had I used `(?<!^)` the string would have been split into `" "`, `"cat"` and `"something"`. Similar for `(?! |$)` instead of `(?!$)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-regex way of doing this:

- split on the separator
- re-join the array using `` `,${separator},` ``
- split the new string on `,`
- filter out any empty values

Note I've used `,` as a new separator; you can use any character that doesn't occur in the original string.

```js
const separator = 'cat'
const match = 'somethingcatsomethingcatsomethingcat'

const result = match.split(separator)
  .join(`,${separator},`)
  .split(',')
  .filter(Boolean)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I need to split an array based on a dynamic separator that will change, and keep the separator in the resulting array. ..."*

Utilize *text formatting*, and the *RegExp* constructor to create the *pattern*.
And, use the *look-around* *syntax*, to assert positions before and after the *delimiter*.

Here is an example.

```
(?=(?<!^)cat)|(?<=cat(?!$))
```

```js
let s = 'somethingcatsomethingcatsomethingcat'
let d = 'cat'
let p = new RegExp(`(?=(?<!^)${d})|(?<=${d}(?!$))`, 'gmi')
let a = s.split(p)

console.log(a.join(', '))
```